# Lebesgue Integrability : for what values of $\alpha$?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\alpha \in [0,1]$. We consider $f_{\alpha} : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow [0,+\infty]$ defined by $f_{\alpha}(x) = \dfrac{ \sqrt{|x|} }{1-x} 1_{[0,\alpha]}(x)$.

We can write $f_{\alpha} (x) = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \dfrac{\alpha^{n+3/2} }{n+3/2}$.

I would like to know what are the values of $\alpha$ for which the function $f_{\alpha}$ is Lebesgue-integrable.
Sorry for my bad english. Thank you in advance.